# Windows Azure Diagnostic Agent has Stopped Working (Exception: StorageAccount is null)

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-storage-emulator

When I start my Azure website role locally I get the dreaded Windows Azure Diagnostics Agent has stopped working dialogue.  In event viewer there is an entry with the below text, StorageAccount is null. is the exception.  In ServiceConfiguration.local I have-

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
       <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
```

The storage emulator is running locally.  My co-worker has what should be an identical set-up on his machine and does not have this problem.

An unhandled exception occurred. Type: System.ArgumentException Process ID: 6628
Process Name: DiagnosticsAgent
Thread ID: 1
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role deployment24(44).XBRLazure.xbrlWebSite_IN_0
Exception: StorageAccount is null.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.StorageUtility.StorageUtility.ValidateStorageAccount()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.ValidateStartupInfo(DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo startupInfo)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.StartWithExplicitConfiguration(DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo startupInfo, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsAgentManager.b__0()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Common.BlockingExecutionEnvironment.Execute(Func`1 entryPoint)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.Program.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 0):

Andrew - what version of Azure SDK are you running? Is this with the latest 2.4 version?
Is this just with one particular VS project? Or can you reproduce it with other VS projects.

You may want to try breaking on exceptions and see if that helps any.
It sounds almost as if your are referencing an incorrect storage connection string, possibly.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been getting this error. Not sure if the same version as the posted question, but I am using 2.2. I also recently installed VS2013, but cannot determine if this was the cause or a recent change to the code (we introduced performance counters to our solution). If I find anything out I will update.